# WSO2 ESB: customizations of Axis2-JSON

Tags: json, wso2, apache-axis, esb, wso2-esb

I would like to correct a JSON parsing error of axis2-json included in WSO2 ESB. The exact filename included is: ./repository/components/plugins/axis2-json-1.6.1.wso2v4.jar

So, I suppose that there are customizations.

What are the exact customizations to axis2-json con respect to the sources of apache.org svn repo?

Are all the changes already upstream?

Can I use a new version of axis2-json like axis2-json-1.6.2?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the source code for the dependencies of WSO2 products at these locations..

- https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/trunk/dependencies
- https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/trunk/dependencies

So I think you can find the axis2-json source code here..
https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/trunk/dependencies/axis2/1.6.1-wso2v5/modules/json

Please feel free to add the issue and submit a patch at [WSO2 JIRA](https://wso2.org/jira/).